# Amazon CTI and Omnichannel not updating

Tags: omnichannel, cti, amazon, softphone

Usually, if you update the omnichannel status to say 'Break' it will update the Phone status to 'Break' and vice versa but this no longer works and no changes have happened. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be an issue with the presence status synchronization between Amazon Connect & SFDC omnichannel. As per the [post](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=308651) ensure you have done these checks

1. Added the Omni-channel Utility item to your App?
2. Did you create the statuses to Amazon Connect and Salesforce with the same names? (different names might also work, but just need to be careful when writing the sync rules)
3. Added the statuses to the Users profile, under: Enabled Service Presence Status Access?
4. Ensure you copy-pasted the correct "Internal name" property to the Call Center field from Service -> Call Center -> callcenters -> Amazon Connect CCP Adapter Lightning X.XX

See Sample sync rule to add to the "Presence sync configuration" to sync statuses bi-directionally

```
 [
    {
      "source": "omni.stateChange",
      "destination": "connect",
      "criteria": {
        "operandA": "omni.agentState",
        "comparator": "===",
        "operandB": "Available"
    },
      "state": "Available"
    },
    {
      "source": "omni.stateChange",
      "destination": "connect",
      "criteria": {
        "operandA": "omni.agentState",
        "comparator": "===",
        "operandB": "Offline"
    },
      "state": "Offline"
    },
    {
      "source": "omni.stateChange",
      "destination": "connect",
      "criteria": {
        "operandA": "omni.agentState",
        "comparator": "===",
        "operandB": "Break"
    },
      "state": "Break"
    },
    {
      "source": "connect.stateChange",
      "destination": "salesforce",
      "criteria": {
        "operandA": "connect.agentState",
        "comparator": "===",
        "operandB": "Available"
    },
      "state": "Available"
    },
    {
      "source": "connect.stateChange",
      "destination": "salesforce",
      "criteria": {
        "operandA": "connect.agentState",
        "comparator": "===",
        "operandB": "Offline"
    },
      "state": "Offline"
    },
    {
      "source": "connect.stateChange",
      "destination": "salesforce",
      "criteria": {
        "operandA": "connect.agentState",
        "comparator": "===",
        "operandB": "Break"
    },
      "state": "Break"
    }
    ]
```

Comment: Where is the prescence sync config? In Salesforce or Amazon Connect?

Comment: You can check the steps in the article https://connect-blogs.s3.amazonaws.com/Amazon+Connect+Salesforce+CTI+Adapter/Amazon+Connect+CTI+Adapter+for+Salesforce+Lightning+-+Setup+and+Installation+Guide.pdf under the section "Create a Presence Sync Rule"

Comment: Thank you Swetha. Do you know how to add the app in Salesforce Classic?

Comment: Can you clarify on which app you are referring to?

Comment: The Omnichannel or Phone App referred to in your instructions

Comment: @Keef10 This article should help to add omni widget to utility bar in classic experience https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=service_presence_add_presence_widget_to_console.htm&type=5

Comment: @Keef10 Have you been able to fix the issue?

Comment: No i am still having issues. Amazon have also upgraded the CCP which has caused functionality to stop

Comment: I have fixed the issue. It was permission based but one issue i now have is that i want the presence status to be one way (i.e Set the phone status and then still be able to take live chats in omnichannel) Any ideas?